# XML::Simple removes root element

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

Hi I have a xml data which i get from array of hashes and when I do a Dumper on it the output is as follows:

```
$var1=
    '<Data>
            <Data1>ABC</Data1>
            <Data2>ABCD</Data2>
    </Data>';
```

This I have in a variable call $var1. Now I am using `XML::Simple` on it.. it is somewhat like: `{Data1=>'ABC',Data2=>'ABCd'};`

The first tag Data is gone. What is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be [well-documented](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm):

> `KeepRoot => 1`:
>
> In its attempt to return a data structure free of superfluous detail
>   and unnecessary levels of indirection, `XMLin()` normally discards the
>   root element name. Setting the `KeepRoot` option to `1` will cause the
>   root element name to be retained.  So after executing this code:
>
> ```
>      $config = XMLin('<config tempdir="/tmp" />', KeepRoot => 1)
> ```
>
> You'll be able to reference the tempdir as
>   `"$config->{config}->{tempdir}"` instead of the default
>   `"$config->{tempdir}"`.

Comment: So this '<config tempdir="/tmp" /> in that "/tmp"/ is what a file name?? I am using a variable her the $var1 i mentioned above..

Comment: `<config ...>` is just an example piece of XML, disregard it. Your problem is addressed by passing `KeepRoot => 1` into `XMLin`:  `my $var2 = XMLin($var1, KeepRoot => 1)`. Now the result will have one `Data` key at the topmost level, representing your outer XML tag.